# Self join query question for getting rows with ids sharing the same values in another field

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a join question that for some reason I am unable to figure out. Here is a simple example of some data with a group_id and location_id. Let's call this table location_data.

| group_id | location_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 3 | 14 |
| 3 | 15 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 4 | 11 |

I need to pull rows that have the same location_id for each group_id. This should get:

| group_id | location_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 25 |
| 2 | 25 |
| 4 | 11 |
| 4 | 11 |

I can get the *opposite* of this, if I use:

```
SELECT *
FROM location_data loc1
JOIN location_data loc2
    ON loc1.group_id = loc2.group_id
    AND loc1.location_id != loc2.location_id;
```

A hacky way of getting the right query is to use that as a subquery and get results that are not in a list of group_ids from that subquery, but I feel like this is an easy one to do with a similar query I used above, and for some reason I am not able to figure out how to properly do this. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Use aggregation:

```
select group_id
from t
group by group_id
having min(location_id) = max(location_id);
```

If you want the original rows rather than just the `group_id`s, then `not exists` is recommended:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.group_id = t.group_id and
                        t2.location_id <> t.location_id
                 );
```